# ng-file-upload open file too slow

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload as documented

```
 <input type="file"
      name="file"
      accept="image/*"
      ngf-max-size="5MB"
      ngf-select="uploadFile($file, form)"
      class="form-control">
```

However, sometimes it takes very long time to open the file dialogue.

Though it never fails, 30s waiting is beyond acceptable.

Has anyone met this before, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: considering the server and internet is in stable stage?

Comment: just click, open the file dialogue and choose the file. Opening the dialogue is very slow. So I don't think the server or internet will lead to this.

Comment: you mean when you reopen your dialog it becomes slower?

Comment: Not always reopen, sometimes the first time opening is slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the accept attribute to "image/png,image/jpg,image/gif". Or your file input can be slow in macos.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg". I had the same issue, this fixed it